# Eclipse Hono command line client is not able to connect to Hono on Sandbox

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, eclipse-hono

I am trying to use the Hono Sandbox as described in "Getting started with Eclipse Hono".

I followed all steps but when starting the command line client I can't connect to the server:

```
12:43:22.465 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.client.impl.HonoConnectionImpl - max 
number of attempts [5] to re-connect to server [hono.eclipseprojects.io:15672, role: unknown] have been made, giving up

12:43:22.489 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.client.impl.HonoConnectionImpl - stopping connection attempt to server [hono.eclipseprojects.io:15672, role: unknown] due to terminal 
error

io.vertx.core.VertxException: Disconnected
```

Even starting the client with:

```
java -jar hono-cli-*-exec.jar --hono.client.host=hono.eclipseprojects.io --hono.client.port=15672 --hono.client.username=consumer@HONO --hono.client.password=verysecret --tenant.id=DEFAULT_TENANT --device.id=4711 --spring.profiles.active=receiver
```

doesn't work. As far as I understand this means, that there is a problem with the network. Verifying that I can access all necessary ports is successful:

```
curl -sIX GET http://hono.eclipseprojects.io:28080/v1/tenants/DEFAULT_TENANT

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
etag: ed4151c3-e694-460e-a21d-c68d5e40411e
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 16
```

And I am able to ping the address (hono.eclipseprojects.io) and access the port (4711).

- I am working on an Raspberry 3B+
- The JDK version I use:

```
java -version 
openjdk version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9+11-post-Raspbian-1deb10u1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.9+11-post-Raspbian-1deb10u1, mixed mode)
```

I highly appreciate any suggestion or idea.

Thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting, the Let's Encrypt certificate we are using with the Sandbox had expired. Should work again ...